# Is there a performance difference between creating startup queues vs dynamic queue in ActiveMQ?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

Most of the examples that I seem to run into are using dynamic queues instead of queue defined during activemq startup (see activemq.xml file). Is there a significant degradation in performance if I use dynamic queue generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It really can be ignored performance-wise